# Select option tag call in javascript function

Tags: javascript, java, html, function, jsp

good morning everyone. I have this form in which there is this select tag and the various input fields.

```
<form class="membership-form webform" name="CreaUtente"
                        action="CreaUtente" onsubmit="document.required()" method="post"
                        role="form">
                        <!-- VALORI UTENTE -->
                        <h6 class="modal-title" id="membershipFormLabel">Dati utente</h6>
                        <select name="select" class="form-control" hidden required>
                            <%
                            for (int j = 0; j < utenti.size(); j++) {
                            %>
                            <option id="list">
                                <%=utenti.elementAt(j).getUsername().toString()%>
                            </option>
                            <%
                            }
                            %>
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome"
                            placeholder="Nome" required> <input type="text"
                            class="form-control" name="cognome" placeholder="Cognome"
                            required> <input type="text" class="form-control"
                            name="email" placeholder="email"> <input type="date"
                            class="form-control" name="data" placeholder="data di nascita"
                            required> 
                            
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                            name="username" id="user" onkeyup="return Control()" placeholder="codice fiscale" required> 
                            <p id="alert">warning</p>
                            
                            <input
                            type="password" class="form-control" name="password"
                            placeholder="Password" required><input type="text"
                            class="form-control" name="numero"
                            placeholder="numero di telefono">

                        <button type="submit" class="form-control" id="submit-button"
                            name="Accedi"
                            style="background-color: #343a40 !important; color: white !important">Crea</button>
                    </form>`
```

I would like to make a function in javascript to check that the value I write in the "username" field is not already present in the select tag. How could I do? I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
`function Control(){
        var username = document.getElementById("user");
        var list = document.querySelectorAll("list");
        var alert = document.getElementById("alert")
        
        for(let i=0; i < list.length; i++){
            if(list[i].value === user.value){
                
                alert.style.color='red';
            }
            else{
                
                alert.style.color='green';
            }
        }
    }`
```

Comment: `Java !== Javascript` (delete tag)

Comment: Use use `user.value` instead use `username.value`

Answer (score 0):

specify # before id name with querySelectorAll as its an id.

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll("#list");
```

And add break when it find a match, as it is again setting green, after matching the next option.

```
if (list[i].value === user.value) {
    alert.style.color = 'red';
    break;
}
```

Comment: Now it works, but it only works with the last element of the option tag. The other elements are not recognized.

Comment: In case of multiple occurrences of value, which you want to search?

Comment: I would like that the value I write in the username field does not correspond to any value present in the select